# Rendered timing in navigation (frame) with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I hard to work for my own transition animation in Frame. But following mysterious problem hit me with deadly deadly damage.

First, here is a sample window. It consists of one frame and one button. Of course it differs to my trunk project, nevertheless, it still showed same problem.

[image]

When I clicked the button, the frame navigates to `Page1`.

[image]

**EDITED : here is source state of Page1. It was taken in VS2010 IDE.**

[image]

So, what is problem? - problem is occurring when I call `RenderToBitmap()` to getting the visual of the destination page. (In this case, destination is the `Page1`.)

I call `RenderToBitmap()` with the following code. Here is all of `MainWindow`'s code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

    Page1 pg1 = new Page1();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.frame.Navigate(pg1); //start to navigate.
    }

    private void frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //SaveVisualToPng is my own static method.
        WPFHelper.SaveVisualToPng("d:\\a.png", pg1);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is a state of visual when `frame_Navigated` is called. The TextBox and the TextBlock was rendered, and CheckBox and RadioButton also Rendered. Mysteriously, but, CheckBox and RadioButtons' checked state (notching image and ellipse image) isn't rendered yet.

[image]

How can I deal this hell forged problem? Of cause this is a very bit things. But I think this part is a basement of my application, so I want to make flawlessly.

**EDITED(2)** here is a source of SaveVisualToPng(). Originally it contains a some methods to help work, like GetDPI, but i omitted that. Instead following code make a same result.

```
public static class WPFHelper
{

    public static void SaveVisualToPng(string path, Visual v)
    {
        int width = Convert.ToInt32(((FrameworkElement)v).ActualWidth);
        int height = Convert.ToInt32(((FrameworkElement)v).ActualHeight);

        RenderTargetBitmap myBmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        myBmp.Render(v);

        if (myBmp != null)
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(myBmp));
            using (Stream stm = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                png.Save(stm);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try to correct spelling and grammar in your question.

Comment: Am I right, you would like to have screenshot of page1 taken? And the problem is, that both, checkbok and radiobutton are not checked in the screenshot? But on the screen these are checked?

Comment: see my edited post WaltiD. thanks for your intrest.

Comment: Where in all this do you check the checkbox/radiobutton?

Comment: these controls were checked in XAML of Page1, not runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if queuing your work on the dispatcher (to give WPF time to render the controls) helps:

```
private void frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Action save = () => WPFHelper.SaveVisualToPng("d:\\a.png", pg1); 
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, save);
}
```

Without your `WPFHelper` implementation I can't test it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Sadly your help didn't work. I'll edit my post soon for SaveVisualToPng. wait a moment.

Comment: @mjk Was my code correct or did you have to change it in some way?

Comment: Basically, I think it was a flaw point of WPF. Because it was inconsistent with checkbox-radiobutton and another controls. But by your trick (which giving a threadical timing to UI thread), the problem was disappeared.

Comment: @mjk then what did you mean by "your help didn't work" in the original comment?

Comment: I modify a code to take a Visual when a Storyboard has beginned, instead before a Storyboard begin. Of course it can't solve a problem, but practically, I satisfied.

Comment: @mjk As much as I love getting the rep, I don't think you should accept my answer if it didn't actually fix the problem. Better to post the solution yourself as an answer and accept that.

Comment: @mjk I don't know what other help I can give you. It sounds like you managed to solve your problem - I was just interested in what the solutionn was, and I suspect others might be too.